# Mechanism to monitor resource usage of an API endpoint

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, metrics

Need to know a mechanism to monitor resource usage (ex: CPU usage, memory usage) of a particular API endpoint (ex: http://localhost:8080/observability). For example, can we use **Prometheus** for this?